# get selected dropdown value and also get the new value if a new option is selected later?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the dropdown value from html select options but want it to get the new value in case another option is selected later

**here is my html code :**

```
<select name="show1" class="show1">
    <option value="Pos1">Position</option>
    <option value="Lot1">Lots</option></select>
```

**I know about getting the selected option:**

```
var slctd = document.getElementById("show1");
var strUser = slctd.value;
```

but how can i incorporate so that it gets the changed value later as well ?
meaning on page load its getting the selected value , and when its changed later on , then it gets the new selected value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener listening for `change` events:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select[name=show1]') // select the element
select.addEventListener( // attach an event listener to it
    'change', // that listens for change events
    function() { // and executes this function when a change event occurs
      console.log(select.value); // you could as well update a global variable here
    }
);
```

```html
<select name="show1" class="show1">
  <option value="Pos1">Position</option>
  <option value="Lot1">Lots</option>
</select>
```

Please note that in the HTML you showed the `select` element does not have an `id`, so it cannot be retrieved using `document.getElementById()`.